# validate the IP address from the given list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, validation, ip-address

I do see answers on the stackoverflow for validating the IPs from given string. I am trying to do the same. However, I have a LIST of IPs.
I am stuck with the following code. Please help.

I appreciate your time!

```
def validateIP(self, IP):

    def is_IPv4():
        i = 0
        while i < len(IP):
             ls = IP[i].split('.')
             if len(ls)== 4 and all( g.isdigit() and (0 >= int(g) < 255) for g in ls):
                 return True
             i += 1
             return False

    def is_IPv6():
        i = 0
        while i < len(IP):
             ls = IP[i].split('.')
             if len(ls) == 8 and all(0 > len(g)< 4 and all( c in '0123456789abcdefABCDE' for c in g) for g in ls):
                 return True
             i += 1
             return False


    for item in IP:
        if '.' in item and is_IPv4():
            return 'IPv4'
        if ':' in item and is_IPv6():
            return 'IPv6'
        return 'Neither'
print(validateIP('n', ['100.243.537.591', 'HBA.KJFH.LSHF', '172.16.254.1', '2001:0db8:85a3:0:0:8A2E:0370:7334', '256.256.256.256']))
```

Comment: What error/issue are you seeing? My initial guess is that the `return False` in the `for` loop is returning when you actually want a list of True/False answers.
I'm also confused why you've written a method with closures, containing `self` which you never use. Did you mean to write a class here?

Comment: @match, I am getting "Neither" as my output. I dont think my loop is getting iterated. I didnt mean to write class, I am a rookie in Python so not sure which is the proper way to write this.

Comment: You will get `Neither` since a return exits a method, so when you call `return Neither` that's the end of the code. This is relatively fundamental 'first lessions' stuff, so I'd advise going back and reading up on how to create methods to see why this is happening and rewrite this code.

Comment: @gabs did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't recreate your functions, but I put this together for you. The code below can easily be added to a function (e.g. ip_address_validation).

```
# Python module for Regular expressions
import re

# Valid IPv4 address format 
IPv4_format = '(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'

# Valid IPv6 address format 
IPv6_format = '(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,' \
      '2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))'


possible_IP_addresses = ['100.243.537.591', 'HBA.KJFH.LSHF', '172.16.254.1', '2001:0db8:85a3:0:0:8A2E:0370:7334', '256.256.256.256']

for address in possible_IP_addresses:

  is_IPv4 = re.compile(r'{}'.format(IPv4_format))
  match_IPv4 = re.match(is_IPv4, address)

  is_IPv6 = re.compile(r'{}'.format(IPv6_format))
  match_IPv6 = re.match(is_IPv6, address)

  if match_IPv4:
    print ('Valid IPv4 address: {}'.format(address))
    # output
    Valid IPv4 address: 172.16.254.1

  elif match_IPv6:
    print ('Valid IPv6 address: {}'.format(address))
    # output
    Valid IPv6 address: 2001:0db8:85a3:0:0:8A2E:0370:7334

  else:
    print ('Not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address: {}'.format(address))
    # output
    Not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address: 100.243.537.591
    Not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address: HBA.KJFH.LSHF
    Not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address: 256.256.256.256
```